# Difference between:- Range(Cells(2,3),Cells(lastRow,3)) and Range("C2:C23")?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a line of vba in which I'm trying to set a Range object referencing a Range on a protected Worksheet. It works fine if I use the following line:

```
Set rngList = wsTemp.Range("C2:C23")
```

But for some reason it breaks with a "Method 'Range' of object 'worksheet' failed" error if I use a similar line:

```
Set rngList = weTemp.Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lastRow, 3))
```

lastRow is an integer and = 23, so both lines should work equally?

Comment: FYI - @Siddharth's answer show the correct approach, but your second version breaks when `wsTemp` is not the ActiveSheet. Calling `Cells()` without a reference to a specific worksheet will mean it defaults to the ActiveSheet. This makes your code dependent on a specific sheet being active, which is usually a bad thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your cells object is not fully qualified. Try this

```
Set rngList = weTemp.Range(weTemp.Cells(2, 3), weTemp.Cells(lastRow, 3))
```

or

```
With weTemp
    Set rngList = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3))
End With
```